# Notepad++ Regex replace Hyphens

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have a HTML and the alt tags are in this format:

```
alt="something-nice-and-beautiful"
```

How do I replace all hyphens `-` with spaces only between the alt tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still wrapping my brain around this one.  My first inclination is to say use this as the search

`(alt="[^"]*?)\-(.*?")`

and then replace with `\1 \2`.  Each time you run it, it will replace one hyphen with one space, just keep doing Replace All until there are no matches left.  I might come up with a more elegant solution if I think about it more but this works.

Comment: I think that expression might match some dashes outside of quotes as well. This might be safer (if it's valid notebook++ regex syntax) find: `(alt="[^-"]*)-` replace: `$1 `

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! But like you said, just have to hit "Replace All" multiple times

Comment: To avoid repeating this activity, if you have fix number of tags, like 3 in this case, so then you can use `(alt="[0-9 A-Z a-z]*)\-(.*)\-(.*)\-(.*)` expression to replace with `$1 $2 $3 $4` This will replace all 3 hyphens in one shot.

Comment: @HåkenLid No, the question mark in `.*?` tells it to take the shortest possible match, this guarantees that the second group stops matching at the first double quote it finds.  Because of that, we don't have to worry about the match moving past the end of the alt attribute.

Comment: @JasonL. There's nothing in your expression that guarantees that the group will not span several double quotes. In this case the shortest match only guarantees that it will not include any hyphens (or newlines, depending on regex flags),

Comment: Try with this example `<a alt="no hyphens here" href="http://www.hyphens-are-us.com">` Unless notepad++ has a very different implementation of non-greedy than other regex implementations, your expression will match outside of the first double quotes, which will be bad, since you will change the url.

Comment: @HåkenLid - Yes!  You're a genius!  I didn't see it before.  Great example.  Based on this, I changed the regex to `(alt="[^"]*?)\-(.*?")`.  That should pass this example now, let me know if you think of another way to break it.

Answer (score 0):

In the source expression (make sure you enable `.*` regular expression button). Since this isn't going to work with a single expression, I'd do this (assuming that at most your tags are of a manageable length of course!)

Search for:

```
(?<=alt=")(\w+)-(?=")
```

Replace with:

```
$1
```

Then search/replace again, adding a `(\w+)-`:

```
(?<=alt=")(\w+)-(\w+)-(?=")
$1 $2
```

And again:

```
(?<=alt=")(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)(?=")
$1 $2 $3
```

...

```
(?<=alt=")(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)(?=")
$1 $2 $3 $4
```

Adding additional words as you go to ensure all your tags are replaced.